# Spring Security - Integration Tests with user

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-mvc-test

I have an integration test for Spring (with Spring Security) that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RootControllerIT {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private URL base;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.base = new URL("http://localhost:" + port + "/");
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void getHello() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity(base.toString(),
                String.class);
        assertThat(response.getBody(), equalTo("OK"));
    }
}
```

My issue is that the `@WithMockUser` does not work here, is there a way to add a mock user to the `TestRestTemplte` or otherwise send authenticated user information to the Integration test?

The mock user works fine when using `MockMvc` to test, but it's obviously not appropriate here.